# How to import data via MySQL Workbench with SSH?

Tags: python, mysql, sql, hosting, pythonanywhere

I'm trying to upload data to my MySQL database on the PythonAnywhere server hosting via SSH (I have a paid account). I have three databases (`alter$default`, `alter$ip_data` and `alter$visitor_data`) from within the PythonAnywhere interface.

Using the online instructions ([here](https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/AccessingMySQLFromOutsidePythonAnywhere/)) I can successfully connect to the server via SSH using MySQL Workbench, and see the three databases in the schemas window ([Click here to view image of schemas list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xURb0.png)).

I can successfully add tables to the database of my choice, but when I try to add data I get `Error Code: 1045. Access denied for user 'alter'@'%' (using password: YES)`.

I have tried troubleshooting:

For `SELECT user();` it returns `alter@10.0.0.89`

For `SELECT current_user();` it returns `alter@%`

For `SHOW GRANTS;` it returns:

```
  GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'alter'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD <secret> WITH MAX_USER_CONNECTIONS 6 
  GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON 'alter$default' .* TO 'alter'@'%' 
  GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON 'alter$visitor_data' .* TO 'alter'@'%' 
  GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON 'alter$ip_data' .* TO 'alter'@'%'
```

It appears that I have the necessary privileges granted and am correctly connected to the MySQL server - so why will it not let me write to the database? Is the .csv file in the wrong place? I can't use the 'root' user as that is surely the PythonAnywhere administrator account?

Extra details: 
The SQL query for writing to the database - that returns "access denied" - is:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'VALUES.CSV'
   INTO TABLE ip_data_table
      FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
      ENCLOSED BY '"'
      LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
IGNORE 0 LINES;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's the infile that is causing the permission denied. You need to start the mysql client with the --local-infile=1 flag.

Comment: And I think it should also be `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE`.

Comment: That's right, using both --local-infile=1 and LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE in combination from the Bash command line has fixed the issue. Thank you!